# Display latest 10 database records in GridView in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I want to display latest 10 database entries in a GridView in C#. Right now i am using this code to display entries from oldest to new ones.

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jason"].ConnectionString;


            string query = "SELECT TOP 10 did,name,mobile from dealer;";
            query += "SELECT TOP 10 CUSTREGNO,DATEOFCOM,PLANANDTERM from customerreg";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(ds);
                            gvCustomers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                            gvCustomers.DataBind();
                            gvEmployees.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
                            gvEmployees.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query?

Comment: Why are you doing `string query = "SELECT... ;"` and then `query += "SELECT ...;`?

Comment: because i have  2 GridView on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it easier if you have an auto-increment primary key. Then you can retrieve those value from "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM **yourTable** ORDER BY **YourPrimaryKey** DESC"